# Consumir data de un webservice en xml con vb.net

Tags: vb.net, xml, webservice

Estoy haciendo una web en vb.net que consuma un webservice que utilice de [Ejemplo](http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx/GetCountries), la cual me devuelve todos los paises.

Solamente tengo un boton <kbd>Enviar</kbd> que manda a llamar los paises y tengo un lbl que me muestra el resultado.

```
Imports service_country = WebServiceVB2.country

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim serv_country As New service_country.country '--Creo el objeto del servicio'
        Dim MyDoc As New System.Xml.XmlDocument
        Dim MyXml As String = serv_country.GetCountries() '--Ejecuto el procedimiento del webservice y lo guardo en string'

        MyDoc.LoadXml(MyXml) '--Leo el contenido del Myxml y lo convierto en XML'
        Dim SymbolText As String = MyDoc.SelectSingleNode("//NewDataSet/Table/Name").InnerText '--Selecciono unicamente el nodo en donde este Name'
        Label1.Text = SymbolText

    End Sub
```

**La pregunta es:** ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que recorra todos los valores del xml?. Ya que actualmente solo me devuelve uno.
Muestro el ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano por su respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Debido a que el documento en XML tiene simbolos como "& g t ;" utilize el siguiente procedimiento:

```
Dim doc1 As XDocument = XDocument.Load(URL)

Dim docStr As String = doc1.ToString()
docStr = docStr.Replace("&gt;", ">")
docStr = docStr.Replace("&lt;", "<")

Dim doc2 As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(docStr)

Dim root As XElement = doc2.Root
Dim defaultNs As XNamespace = root.GetDefaultNamespace()
Dim names() As String = doc2.Descendants(defaultNs + "Name").Select(Function(x) CType(x, String)).ToArray()
For Each nombres In names
  Label1.Text = Label1.Text & nombres
Next
```

[Mas información de la respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43991304/consuming-data-from-webservice-with-vb-net/43991955#43991955)